# setting jTextField values dynamically

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, jtextfield, settext

First, I'm new to java. Lately encountered a problem like this.

I have an integer array like,

```
 int[] data={32,12,31,89,90};
```

then, I have 5 jTextFields.

I named them as jNum0,jNum1,...,jNum4. Problem is that according to the program I'm working on

I need to print each value in array in respective textbox by **using a loop**.

Like:

```
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++){ 
//<jNum+i>.setText(data[i]);
// This actually doesn't work
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Better create an 'array of TextField'

```
TextField tf[] = new TextField[5];
```

And after this, call `for loop` as

```
for(int i=0;i<=4;i++)
{
     tf[i].setText(data[i]);
}
```

It will work.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was creating the program by using netbeans IDE. So, I've already created TextFields. Is there a way to do modifications to them

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve by creating an array of JTextFields and refer each JTextField by its index. You will be able to access each JTextField by its index and your problem would be solved.

jTexts are just classes and like any other class in Java you can easily create an array of objects of type jText.

For more help use this link:

[Creating array of JTextFields](http://www.coderanch.com/t/367570/java/java/create-Array-JTextField)

Answer (score 0):

You have hata in array. Put jTextFields in array too.

```
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[5];
for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i] = new JTextField();
}

for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].setText(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using netbeans IDE? because we already create textfields there.